# CSS :hover dropdown. Just need a pointer

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu, html-lists

Hi all I am working on a project and am trying to do this all by hand for a learning exercise.  I am not looking for the code that does the job but just an explanation of how this should be done.

the page I am working on is http://dev.davydsoft.com/playing.html

What I would like is to have a dropdown "menu" image  when you hover over the pics up top.  This is inspired and by the twitter bar. When you click on your user name on the twitter bar you get that dropdown.

I have played with alot of examples and for some reason it just wont click for me.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the stack overflow! I would recommend that you take a look at the first tutorial on this page:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers

It explains how to use jquery (javascript) to show and hide hidden html elements.

If you are looking for a css only solution, you might search for "css suckerfish menu".

Comment: OK I finally got what I was looking for. JQuery .slideToggle.  dev.davydsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript for the hover event css for styling and html

Comment: You don't necessarily need JS. You can even do animations with css3.

Comment: OK I finally got what I was looking for. JQuery .slideToggle.  dev.davydsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Basically, if you only want guidance, then start looking into how to style with :hover selectors.

Comment: OK I finally got what I was looking for. JQuery .slideToggle.  dev.davydsoft.com